# Backbone.js Router Matching Optional Parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, routes

I'm trying to create a backbone router that can match optional parameters.

Consider the following code:

```
routes: {  
  '/jobs'                                     : 'jobs',
  '/jobs/p:page'                              : 'jobs',
  '/jobs/job/:job_id'                         : 'jobs',
  '/jobs/p:page/job/:job_id'                  : 'jobs'
}

jobs: function(page, job_id){
   // do stuff here ....
}
```

If I navigate to URL abc.com/**#/jobs/p104/** the **page** parameter will be **104**.  However, if navigate to abc.com/**#/jobs/job/93**, the **job_id** parameter is **undefined** but the **page** parameter is **93**.

So Backbone's router basically matches the routes hash parameters by order and not by name.

I know the solution would be to use a *splat and split the parameters with regex, but I can't seem to get the regex part to work (my regex is pretty rusty).  Can someone please help?

If there's a better solution than using *splat, can someone please share?

Comment: Backbone 0.9.9 has optional parameters using (). For example /jobs(/p:page)(/job/:job_id)

Comment: @opengrid - any idea how to handle optional params in your route handling functions?

Comment: @mikeyUX what do you mean? Adding their names as function parameters should do the trick

Answer (score 21):

Instead of messing with regexes it would be easier and less error prone just to have a second function. You will probably have to bindAll this in an initialize function for this.jobs to work.

```
routes: {  
  '/jobs'                                     : 'jobs',
  '/jobs/p:page'                              : 'jobs',
  '/jobs/job/:job_id'                         : 'jobsId',
  '/jobs/p:page/job/:job_id'                  : 'jobs'
},

jobs: function(page, job_id){
   // do stuff here ....
},

jobsId: function(page, job_id){
   this.jobs(undefined, job_id
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more restful to have: /jobs for the listing and just a regular query string parameter for pageing (because it drives the view and not the content) like /jobs?page=10. And for a certain job use /jobs/<id> as by convention. Because for pageing you might require more parameters like offset or rows as well. And you could have filter options as well. You don't want to add all that to your path, even with backbone. https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

try this (single regex, works on all your input formats)

```
var re = /\/jobs(?:\/p(\d+))?.*?(?:\/(\d+)|$)/;
var matches = 'abc.com/#/jobs/p104/4'.match(re);
var page=false;var job=false;
if (matches != null) {
    var page = matches[1] || false;
    var job = matches[2] || false;
}; 
alert("page:" + page + ",job:" + job)
```

**matches first the pNNN segment if it is there, and uses a non greedy quantifier with dot `.` that can eat anything `.*?` to crawl up the string one by one, so that the second group (just /NNN) will also match if present. the `(?: exp )` are non-capturing groups, they group, but they don't "remember" anything.

Comment: when I elaborated, I also fixed the regex (added end of string anchor to force the last group to match, if present)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing a lot of these, you might glance at [this pattern](http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/12/regex-routing-with-backbone-js/) for wrapping them up tidily. For just these, though, the following regexs ought to do it:

```
/\/jobs\/p(\d+)/              => /jobs/pXXX
/\/jobs\/p(\d+)\/job\/(\d+)/  => /jobs/pXXX/job/XXX
```

You can then use `String.match` with the splats you retrieve to extract the url fragments in question. Using strings in place of a `splat` variable:

```
var matches = '/jobs/p18'.match(/\/jobs\/p(\d+)/);
var page = matches[1];

var matches = '/jobs/p4/job/6/'.match(/\/jobs\/p(\d+)\/job\/(\d+)/);
var page = matches[1];
var job = matches[2];
```